# CSS background - fixed cover - обрезается снизу

Tags: css, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Мне нужно вставить рамку как фиксед бакграунд страницы.
Казалось бы что проще, вставь бакграунд, задай background-size: cover; и она растянется до нужных размеров. Но нет.
Результат проще посмотреть тут:

https://formula-news.ru/prob/

И что странно, что когда смотришь с живого монитора - то нижней рамки нет.
проверял на 1920х1080 и 1366х768.

Но если смотришь через инструменты разработчика - Toogle Device Toolbar - там все отлично, для всех разрешений.

```css
.main_block {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}

.pre_border {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
}


.full_border {
    background: url(https://i.ibb.co/R7JMV9W/border.png) no-repeat;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
  <div class="main_block">
      <div class="pre_border">
             <div class="full_border"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно изменить  `background-size: cover;` на  `background-size: 100% 100%;` для блока `full_border`.

> cover ---
> Ключевое слово, обратное contain. Масштабирует изображение как можно больше c сохранением пропорций изображения (изображение не становится сплющенным). Когда изображение и контейнер имеют разные размеры, изображение обрезается либо влево / вправо, либо сверху / снизу.

Ссылка на [ресурс](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Или вариант самому в графическом редакторе изменить размер рамки

Comment: Тогда картинка будет сжиматься теряя свои пропорции. Уж лучше тогда `auto 100%` (высота всегда 100%, а ширина подстраивается) или `100% auto` (ширина 100%, а высота подстраивается)

Comment: Попробовал два ваших варианта: 
1. auto 100% - рамка по высоте хорошо, зато по ширине только до половины не дотягивает
2. 100% auto - ширина хорошо, нижний край пропал

Как мне кажется при варианте 100% 100% - не настолько критично сжатие, и выглядит довольно хорошо

Comment: Да, спасибо. То что надо! :)

Comment: Рад что ваша проблема решена )

Answer (score 1):

Если вам так сильно нужен низ картинки, то можете добавить `background-position: center bottom`, тем самым картинка сохранит пропорции за счёт `cover`, но будет прижиматься нижней частью к нижней границе блока.

Comment: Пробовал ваш вариант, background-position: center bottom - низ картинки хорошо, а вот вверх пропал

Comment: Тогда используйте `background-size: auto 100%`, но учтите, что если ширина картинки будет меньше ширины границы, то будут пустоты по краям.